# React too many re-renders because of data loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this chunk of code:

```
export default function CloseInquiryComponent(props) {

    const auth = getAuth();
    const db = getFirestore();

    const { id } = useParams();

    const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState("");

    // get user 
    const [user, authLoading, authErr] = useAuthState(auth);
    // get user data of a collection
    const [userData, userDataLoading, dataErr] = useDocumentData(
      user ? doc(db, `users/${user.uid}`) : null,
    );

    // get the inquiry data
    const [inquiry, inquiryLoading, inquiryError] = useDocumentData(doc(db, "תקלות", id));

    // show loading until data is done loading
    if(inquiryLoading)
    {
        return <LoadingComponent/>
    }

    // this causes an error because there is a return before it.
    setSomeVar(inquiry.SomeData);
```

If I remove the if statement and try to set there, it might be null.
If I try something like:

```
if(!inquiryLoading)
{
    setSomeVar(inquiry.SomeData);
    return <pagehtmlhere/>
}
```

I get an error "too many re-renders".

each re-render calls the function and sets the variable, which causes more re-renders.

How can I set the data once it's been loaded, while also keeping the react rules in mind?

Comment: You should use `useEffect` hook. Changing state variable on render phase produces side effects.

Comment: Could you give an example in an answer?

Comment: I think you should read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `useEffect` hook.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (inquiryLoading && inquiry) setSomeVar(inquiry.SomeData);
}, [inquiryLoading, inquiry])
```

Comment: `inquiry` should also be in the dependency array.